# Why i am getting client certificate error?

Tags: authentication

I tried to open URL with mutual authentication for 8443 but I am getting client certificate error.I need to clarify why this happening, Can any one tell me what is the issue. PFA..

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must follow these steps to upload a certificate otherwise you will be gettng error *Client certificate error:No client certificate provided* for port 8443.

1. Click Upload Mutual Authentication Certificate.
2. Give your certificate a label and name and click Choose File to locate the certificate.
3. Click Save to finish the upload process.
4. Enable the “Enforce SSL/TLS Mutual Authentication” user permission for an “API Only” user. This “API Only” user configures the API client to connect on port 8443 to present the signed client certificate.

> Note that the client certificate must include any intermediate
>   certificates in the certificate chain when contacting port 8443. A
>   certificate chain is an hierarchical order of certificates where one
>   certificate issues and signs another certificate lower in the
>   hierarchy. Upload a certificate chain as a single PEM-encoded
>   **CA-signed certificate**.